# Handling mixed types using sqlalchemy TypeDecorator

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am modelling a TimeSeries in sqlalchemy as a one-to-many style collection of TimeSeriesValue objects. The TimeSeriesValue objects contain a DateTime and a value of type Numeric. Sometimes it's necessary to model time-series of non-numeric data. How can I make my TimeSeriesValue object more generic? I thought of using a TypeDecorator to build a generic value type:

```
class TimeSeriesValueType(sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator):

    impl = sqlalchemy.types.String

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return str(value)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return <convert value to some specific type>
```

The issue here is `return <convert value to some specific type>` since I don't know what type to convert the underlying String value to. If could add an attribute to the TimeSeries object that indicated the intended Python type of the TimeSeriesValue then I could use it to do the conversion, but the TimeSeriesValueType cannot see this at conversion time. Does anyone have a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: It sounds like you have a *table* with two columns per row, and *not* a *single value in a column*. Make it a model, not a type.

Comment: For a one-to-many relationship, your timeseries table then has `(foreign_key, datetime_value, numeric_value)` rows, and SQLAlchemy will give you tools to create a relationship between this table and another.